# Matplotlib set_yticklabels shifting

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart

Given the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 5.7]
y = np.arange(len(x))
fsize=(2,2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=fsize)
ax.set_yticklabels(['a','b','c','d'])
ax.barh(y,x,align='center',color='grey')
plt.show()
```

Why are the labels not showing as expected ('a' does not show up and everything is shifted down by 1 place)?

[image]

Comment: FWIW in recent matplotlib you can just do `y = list('abcd')`.

Comment: @Goyo. Very neat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The locator is generating an extra tick on each side (which are not being shown because they is outside the plotted data). Try the following:

```
>>> ax.get_yticks()
array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```

You have a couple of options. You can either hard-code your tick labels to include the extra ticks (which I think is a bad idea):

```
ax.set_yticklabels(list(' abcd')) # You don't really need 'e'
```

Or, you can set the ticks to where you want them to be along with the labels:

```
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(list('abcd'))
```

A more formal solution to the tick problem would be to set a [`Locator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating) object on the y-axis. The tick label problem is formally solved by setting the [`Formatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) for the y-axis. That is essentially what is happening under the hood when you call `set_yticks` and `set_yticklabels` anyway, but this way you have full control:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter

...

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(y))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedFormatter(list('abcd')))
```

Comment: This method doesn't work regardless of using formatter and locator.

Comment: @Ash. Which version?

Answer (score 0):

No, none of that works for me on Windows, Python 3.7.
Just print it as text with the x-axis location slightly to the left of the smallest x value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax.set_yticklabels("")
x = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 5.7]
y = np.arange(len(x))
fsize=(2,2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=fsize)
    names = ['a','b','c','d']
    for i in np.arange(len(x)):
        plt.text(-0.05,len(x)-i-1,names[i])
    plt.show()
```